# Avoid global variables in Node, how to return the body of a request from a POST call

Tags: node.js, api, http, callback, request

I'm still new to Node so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but some searching isn't helping so here we are.

I'm making a request to an API to get weather data. I can get the data and log it to the console no problem, but I'm having trouble getting the body of the request to end up in the response to the original POST.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');   

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// make the web server use body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});

// Send information from the weather API to the console
app.post('/processWeather', function (req, res) {

    requestString = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=7839805&appid=xxxxxxxx';

    request(requestString, function(err, res, body){    
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {        
        console.log(body);          
    }   
  });

  //redirect back to homepage after getting the weather 
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

So the problem with this is that I can't simply use the **body** variable in the **app.post** callback. I'm suspicious this is to do asynchronous logic but I'm as I'm new I can't wrap my head around the best way to do this without using a global variable to temporarily store the **body** variable. How can I get the contents of the **body** variable sent back to the browser? Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables unless it's absolutely necessary!

You can use session.

```
req.session['weather'] = weatherData;  // Weather data
res.redirect("/");
```

You can use a lot of other ways also. But this is what I'd prefer.

Comment: I agree, don't use global variable :)

So session is unique to each visitor? I.e are multiple users running this going to cause trouble for each other?

Comment: Please read about sessions: https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed. All I had to do was place the request in the res.send

```
res.send(request(requestString));
```